# Automate email to packer in the morning

Tags: shopify

Is there a way or method to email my distributor all of my orders that need to be fullfilled that have been placed by 1am on thursday the morning of friday at 7am?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can send emails like that by [setting up a custom fulfillment service](https://help.shopify.com/manual/shipping/rates-and-methods/fulfillment-services/custom).
There would be one email per order however.

If you would rather have the emails go out in batches then there are [third-party apps](https://apps.shopify.com/search/query?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=export+orders) like [Xporter](https://apps.shopify.com/xporter-by-eshop-admin) that can do the trick. Or you could build your own app using the [Orders API.](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/order)